# jquery scrolled event runs code multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, standards

So with the following code the `console.log` outputs scrolled to the dev tools console multiple times while scrolling the page.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
        console.log("scrolled");
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
});
```

So if I have a bunch of javascript which controls seting the navbar to sticky, it effectively runs many times. This seems like a bad approach.

I tried to prevent the scroll event by using the following code:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
        console.log("scrolled");
        //do something
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
});
```

But it still outputs scrolled to dev tools multiple times.
I also tried using a break statement as @jswebb suggested but it gives me this js error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Here is a screenshot showing the output.

[image]

How can I prevent this code from running multiple times, but rerun if the `$(this).scrollTop() !> 25`, so in the else statement.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Sorry, I'm a dolt - I saw that your log was repeating and in my head, I instantly thought, "LOOP!" Except there isn't a loop here; it's just that your console is logging the output every time you scroll beyond your parameter.

I don't think this is necessarily a bad thing; it's not that you have code that's firing every time you scroll, you're just telling your console to log right now all of the times you scroll beyond 25.

As far as your real-world sticky header, I wonder if this is an issue?

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
        $("header").addClass("fixed");
    }
    else {
        $("header").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

You'd just set it up to add a class that makes your header fixed beyond 25 - the code you'd use IRL would only fire once @ the threshold you set.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65tu3wem/)

---

Have you tried using a `break` statement to exit the conditional after your limit has been hit?

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
        console.log("scrolled");
        //do something
        break;
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. break gives me this js error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`

Comment: I See your point, I thought because `console.log("scrolled");` was firing many times then my code must be. But I guess the code doesn't run multiple times. must be some kind of jquery thing where the same code isn't alowwed to run to often. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: No problem! And it's not a jQuery thing, it's just that this particular case only has methods that are firing once. You could certainly write jQuery that fires multiple times, but here were just adding a simple class @ 25. That action wouldn't happen more than once because how could it? Cheers!